# Is Omega Supreme the only Guardian Robot who can transform?

Tags: transformers

In the Transformers G1 cartoon, Guardian Robots are seen a couple of times, one battling Superion, another battling autobots, but as far as I remember, they never transform.

Omega Supreme however, can turn into a rocket, a rocket base and a tank.

Is Omega Supreme the only Guardian Robot who can transform?